# How to find the overlapping records in a Trips made from a Driver using Start and End Date Time

Tags: sql, hana

I have a Trip data set as below where I have Trips for a given drivers and its associated vehicles and its Start and End Date Time.

[Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGRO9.png)
[image]

From the above, I have Trips where there is a overlap between Start Date Time and End Date Time between its records.

[Processed Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMnbz.png)
[image]

That implies a Driver traveled or made a trip more than once at any given time which is not possible as a single driver can drive one vehicle at the given period.

So, I would like to extract them from the data set leaving behind the non-overlapping or the correct ones as below.

[Final Requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3j72u.png)
[image]

Could you please suggest the SQL for the above requirement.

Best Regards,

Comment: consider posting actual pieces of code and input/output data instead of pictures

Comment: Please do not post pictures. Add the tables as text so we can reproduce the case easily. You want answers, don't you?

Comment: Trip 4_12_1306 is removed because it is a 2nd trip on the same day for the same driver. But trip 2_12 and 7_12 are first trip by driver 1235. Why is it not removed and you keep trip ID 8_12 and 11_12? The rule is not consistent between the drivers

Comment: @TheImpaler: Extremely sorry for posting pictures as I could not find the way to post a table in the detail section and it was considering as text and forming a paragraph. So, I have used an approach of pictures.

Comment: @sotona: I will check the way to post tables in my next updates. Thanks.

Comment: you can just wrap them as a code block and your initial formatting will be kept.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ: Thank you for the reply. I have not considered the Trip 4_12_1306 because its Start Date Time and End Date Time entries does not overlap with any of the records where the Driver is 1234. Similarly I have not considered 2_12_1306 and 7_12_1306 for a driver 1235 because those two trip's Start Date Time and End Date Time does not overlap with other records where Driver is 1235.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ: If we take a trip 1_12_1306 and 3_12_1306 for a driver 1234, he has started one Trip from 11 AM to 1:10 PM and 12:10 PM to 1:30 PM respectively. Practically, for a given Driver, he cannot start a next trip until and unless he completes the current trip. So it is false in this case, hence it needs to be shown as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a temporary table cte to collect all tripID that are overlapping per driver. Then I will use these tripID to join to the original table.  See below and sample here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/236dd/3

```
with cte as ( 
    select t1.tripID as ID1, 
           t2.tripID as ID2
    from yourTable t1
    join yourTable t2 
    on t1.driverid=t2.driverid
    where t1.startdatetime between t2.startdatetime and t2.enddatetime
    and t1.tripID > t2.tripID)
select distinct tripID,
       driverid,
       vehicleid,
       startdatetime,   
       enddatetime 
from yourTable t, cte
where t.tripId = cte.ID1
or t.tripId = cte.ID2
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have not considered the Trip 4_12_1306 because its Start Date Time and End Date Time entries does not overlap with any of the records where the Driver is 1234. Similarly I have not considered 2_12_1306 and 7_12_1306 for a driver 1235 because those two trip's Start Date Time and End Date Time does not overlap with other records where Driver is 1235

Comment: If we take a trip 1_12_1306 and 3_12_1306 for a driver 1234, he has started one Trip from 11 AM to 1:10 PM and 12:10 PM to 1:30 PM respectively. Practically, for a given Driver, he cannot start a next trip until and unless he completes the current trip. So it is false in this case, hence it needs to be shown as output

Comment: Thanks. I now understand your requirements and I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much  âńōŋŷXmoůŜ, the SQL helped! In fact the sub query along with Start Date Time and End Date Time gave right info adjacent to each other!

Comment: select t1.tripID as ID1, 
           t2.tripID as ID2
    from yourTable t1
    join yourTable t2 
    on t1.driverid=t2.driverid
    where t1.startdatetime between t2.startdatetime and t2.enddatetime
    and t1.tripID > t2.tripID